# How to use a child class method when the Dictionary has the abstract class as value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, abstract-class

I am making a chess game and I have an abstract class named cls_ChessPieces and a class for every chess piece (cls_Pawn, cls_Knight, ...).

```
class cls_ChessPieces
{

}
class cls_Pawn : cls_ChessPieces
{

 public bool CheckLegalMove()
    {
        // this is the method I want to call
    }
}
```

I made this abstract class because I want to store every chess piece in a dictionary with the location on the chess board as Key (string).

```
private Dictionary<string, cls_ChessPieces> _dicPieces;
_dicPieces.Add((Column + Row), _pawn);
```

After making a move I want to know the type of the piece that has moved.

```
_chessLogic.DicPieces.TryGetValue(key, out piece1);
```

When I put a breakpoint and inspect the piece1 object, I can see which type it has (cls_Pawn). But this type is only given to that object at runtime. This makes it impossible to call the CheckLegalMove() method.

This is the way I solve this issue, but I don't think this is the proper way of doing it. It takes a lot of code do to this for every chess piece class and every time that I want to pass the object I need to do this again.

```
if (piece1 is cls_Pawn)
   {
       cls_Pawn pawn= (cls_Pawn)piece1;
       pawn.CheckLegalMove();
   }
```

Is there an easy way to get the cls_pawn class out of the dictionary an call the CheckLegalMove() method? I tried to get the type :

```
Type t = piece1.GetType();
```

But I don't know if it is possible to cast with this type

```
(t)piece1;
```

Thanks!

Edit:

CheckLegalMove() is maybe not a good example

```
public bool Promote()
    {
        // this is a method only this child class should have
    }
```

Comment: rethink the architecture. the `CheckLegalMove` is a valid question to ask of every piece, so it's declaration should belong in the abstract base class anyway

Comment: re edit: in this case, the typical pattern would be to still have `Promote` a base class method, throwing a `NotSupportedException` on any but the pawn implementation.

Comment: @Cee Throwing NotSupportedExceptions is rarely if ever the correct choice (you're basically working around the static type system). For Promote I can think of several better options depending on the overall choice. One simple option would be to make it `Piece Promote() => this;` as the default implementation in the base class and only overwrite it in the pawn class, there are other possibilities.

Comment: I think for solving such issues you have to use some patterns. For example, Visitor pattern can be applied for such case.

Answer (score 2):

I guess every type of chess item needs to check moves,  so declare method in base class:

```
public abstract class cls_ChessPieces
{
    public abstract bool CheckLegalMove();
}

class cls_Pawn : cls_ChessPieces
{
    public override bool CheckLegalMove()
    {
        // this is the method I want to call
    }
}
```

you will be able to call `CheckLegalMove()` for every class, derived from `cls_Pawn`:

```
bool ok = piece1.CheckLegalMove();
```

Comment: I understand that maybe it is better to create CheckLegalMove() in the bass class. But what if I create a method Promote() that allows the pawn to promote to another piece. This method should only belong in the child class cls_Pawn.

Comment: @jlepers, yes, I agree that Promote() should not be in base class. But may be it shouldn't be in Pawn class either. Some kind ChessBoard class should have it, and replace pieces on board (remove Pawn and create a new piece)

Comment: @jlepers in that case use pattern matching e.g. `if (piece1 is cls_Pawn pawn) { pawn.CheckLegalMove() }`, which is more concise than your example. Although this requires C#7 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I suppose you don't want to have an abstract `CheckLegalMove` method in the `cls_ChessPieces` base class. If this is not a problem don't choose this approach.

#### Approach 1 (not recommended)

You could get the type of the object with

```
var type = piece1.GetType();
```

and then inspect per reflection if the type defines the method `CheckLegalMove()` by doing

```
var type = piece1.GetType();
var checkLegalMoveMethod = type.GetMethod("CheckLegalMove");

if(checkLegalMoveMethod != null)   
{  
    var result = (bool)checkLegalMoveMethod.Invoke(piece1);  
}
```

This works but only as long as your CheckLegalMove method doesn't contain any parameters.

#### Approach 2 (the recommended way)

One thing you could also do is introduce another base class (again only do this if you don't want to have a CheckLegalMove method directly inside `cls_ChessPieces`) `<SubBaseClassName>` which is defined as the following:

```
class <SubBaseClassName> : cls_ChessPieces 
{
     public abstract bool CheckLegalMove();
}
```

The your `cls_Pawn` would inherit from `<SubBaseClassName>` and you could just check if `piece1` is of type `<SubBaseClassName>` and if it is call the `CheckLegalMove` method on it.

Comment: This scenario doesn't require reflection.

Comment: As already mentioned in my answer approach 2 is the recommended way and approach 1 would be only necessary if he really doesn't want to have an abstract method anywhere